# How can I avoid these defects in ContourPlot3D output on WPC?

Tags: plotting, arbitrary-precision

What I do:

```
ContourPlot3D[-x^2/17.07 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 - x^17.07,
       {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 16]
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want: no defects along the edge.

The solution is not to simply increase `PlotPoints`:

```
ContourPlot3D[-x^2/1.3 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 - x^17.07,
       {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 17]
```

[image]

I have read the tutorial ["Arbitrary Precision Numbers"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html)

> "If you give higher‐precision input, the Wolfram Language will use
>   higher precision in its internal calculations, and you will usually be
>   able to get a higher‐precision result."

but I found:

```
ContourPlot3D[-x^2/1.300000000000000000000000000 + y^2 + z^2 == 
       1 - x^17.0700000000000000000000000000,
       {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 16]
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Chuy's suggestion fails:

```
ContourPlot3D[-x^2/1.3+y^2+z^2 ==1-x^17.07,
       {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
       Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 16, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

[image]

---

I am using WPC Free and no other platform. I don't know if these defects appear on any other platform, but I am asking for a solution for WPC.

[Plan details](https://billing.wolframcloud.com/pricing.html?p=wpc) show no difference in memory limit across plans. EDIT: little difference across plans https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gri9.png .

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Try setting `MaxRecursion->0`

Comment: Click on "EXPAND" which is to the right of "BY THE NUMBERS"

Comment: @chuy 1) "Try setting MaxRecursion->0" No joy. 2) I don't see EXPAND or BY THE NUMBERS. Note: I am using Wolfram Programming Cloud.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks. That Q&A seems inapplicable to WPC, but I have added the code my way, which seems to work.

Comment: You're welcome -- I get the same thing on a Macbook Pro (V10.2): http://i.stack.imgur.com/1bFl7.png

Comment: On both WPC and the desktop, I get identical results. The result with `MaxRecursion -> 0` looks reasonably smooth compared to not, so we need to decide if that edge is an artifact or what is actually expected.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that `x^17.07` gives a complex value for `x < 0`.  If you plot over `{x, 0, 2}`, you get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1LMct.png

Comment: I was about to suggest what @MichaelE2 has just written: `ContourPlot3D[-x^2/(13/10) + y^2 + z^2 == 1 - x^(1707/100), {x, 0, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0]`, instead of writing `1.3000000` and `17.07000000000` etc.

Comment: As @blochwave notes, every time you hit something like this, one of the first things to try is to make sure all the numbers in the function you're plotting are exact. `Rationalize[]` is useful in that regard.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I don't think `17.07` vs. `1707/1000` makes much difference in this case.  (I tried it both ways. [`x^(1707/1000)` is just as problematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kphBh.png) as `x^17.07` for `x < 0`..)

Comment: @Michael, that's too bad. Nevertheless, OP should now know that the problem is inherently in the function itself, and not the numbers within it.

Comment: Is it as simple? `ContourPlot3D[-x^2/1.3 + y^2 + z^2 + x^17.07 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0]`

Comment: In the Plan Details link you provided, there is a box "EXPAND" which is to the right of "BY THE NUMBERS".  It will show the session memory limit for the free tier is 500 Mb.

Comment: Add more `PlotPoints` then.

Comment: @Lou, That works... but at the cost of removing PlotPoints and hence loss of quality.

Comment: @chuy, as the question shows, adding just one to PlotPoints causes fail on memory limit. How this little plot can need >0.5Gb is beyond me!

Comment: @blochwave, Thanks for your improvements, but your removal of "on WPC" left my question misrepped. I restored it. My question is "How can I avoid these defects in ContourPlot3D output on WPC?" Not "How can I avoid these defects in ContourPlot3D output?" That won't change until/unless I accept an answer that covers non-WPC too.

Comment: @ Michael E2, I think you're right in accusing the complex number. Thanks. I can see how that 'real == complex' might give that. Will avoid!

Comment: Try, `ContourPlot3D[-x^(20/10)/(13/10) + y^(20/10) + z^(20/10) == (10/10) - 
   x^(1707/100), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 2]`

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good on WPC

```
ContourPlot3D[-x^(20/10)/(13/10) + y^(20/10) + z^(20/10) == (10/10) - 
   x^(1707/100), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 2]
```

[image]